# Multi line form filling with iTextSharp

Tags: pdf, itext

I'm tring to fill a PDF file that has some different form fields, one of those field is a multi line field. I load the values from a txt file (I have to repeat this operation in batch so I've a single txt file for each pdf I've to fill)

My problem is with the \r\n present in the txt file... if I pass on each formfield it writes something as "My text\r\n on new line").

I've tried to use a stringbuilder and .AppendLine method and if I save it's content it correctly shows

My text
on new line

my input file is defined as

```
<map>
  <campoModulo>lo_some_data</campoModulo>
  <value>My text\r\non new line</value>
</map>
```

and here's the code I use to fill the pdf

```
internal void Process(string p)
    {
        string output = p.Replace(".pdf", "_new.pdf");

        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(p);
        XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();

        document.Load("XML\\mapping.xml");

        var items = document.SelectNodes("//map");
        PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(
            output, FileMode.Create));

        var acro = pdfStamper.AcroFields;
        if (items.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (XmlNode item in items)
            {
                var campo = item.SelectSingleNode("campoModulo").InnerText;
                var valore = item.SelectSingleNode("value").InnerText;

                acro.SetField(campo, valore);
            }
        }

        pdfStamper.FormFlattening = true;
        pdfStamper.Close();

    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace the `\r\n` for the actual control codes. Try:

`text = text.Replace(@"\r\n", "\r\n");`